# Problem with tagging multiple friends on photo using Facebook graph

Tags: flash, facebook-graph-api, actionscript-3

I try to tag multiple friends on the phot using the Graph API AS3 for my Flash application. If I'm using a value statically the result is success and works like a charm But when I try to feed the `params.tags` with a dynamic value I get from the array (populated from checkbox) it fails.

Here's the dynamic and failed ones:

```
var arrUserID:Array = new Array("1447615481","1052646429");

var len:Number = arrUserID.length;
var someStr:String = "";
for (var i:Number=0;i<len;i++) {
    someStr += arrUserID[i]+","+Math.round(Math.random()*imgHolder.width)+","+Math.round(Math.random()*imgHolder.height);
    if(i != len-1){
        someStr += "||";
    }
}

var arr:Array = [];
arr = someStr.split("||");

var outputArr:Array = [];

var len2:Number = arr.length;

var temp:Array = [];

for (var j:Number=0;j<len2;j++) {
    temp = arr[j].toString().split(",");
    outputArr.push({'tag_uid':temp[0], 'x':temp[1], 'y':temp[2]});
}

var params:Object = new Object();
params.image = bitmap;
params.message = "YEZAAA";
params.fileName = "file-name";
**params.tags = JSON.encode(outputArr);** --> dynamic value from array

Facebook.api('me/photos', onSaveToPhotoAlbumComplete, params);
```

and here are the success version and the statical ones:

```
var params:Object = new Object();
params.image = bitmap;
params.message = "YEZAAA";
params.fileName = "file-name";
params.tags = '[{tag_uid:"12345678","x":"0","y":"0"},{tag_uid:"001 111","x":"0","y":"0"}]';

Facebook.api('me/photos', onSaveToPhotoAlbumComplete, params);
```

So it just keep me wondering, what is my wrong actually?

There is really a need here since I've been pulling my hair after a week try to figure out, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I got my dynamic id's to work with your code:

1) You have to remember that, like your static code, the tags parameter needs to ultimately result in a `String`. Your dynamic version is using an actual `Object`. So keep it a String like so:

```
var tagsArr:String = '[{tag_uid:"' + uid1 + '", "x":"0", "y":"0"},
                       {tag_uid:"' + uid2 + '", "x":"0", "y":"0"}]';
```

Comment: Thanks for da tips Andrei Sfat...actually I figure out already..Correction here..actually the static version I'm getting from this wonderful community (someone has posted credit to him ..which is I forgot already)